# Conditional probability of 2 draws of balls.

Tags: probability

Given 5 red balls and 4 white balls. 2 balls are drawn in succession from the bag without replacement and it was noted that the second one is white. What is the probability that the first ball is also white?

My solution:

Probability of RW = (5/9)*(4/8)

Probability of WW = (4/9)*(3/8)

Required probability = WW / (RW + WW) = 3/8.

The answer given is 4/9.

[image]

Comment: $P(B)$ in the given solution is wrong. That is not the independent probability of second ball being white.

Comment: Your answer is correct.